# Apache2.4.51 ошибка pip install mod_wsgi на Python 3.9.2

Tags: python-3.x, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

Установил Apache и попытался установить mod_wsgi через команду pip install mod_wsgi. Появился вот такой вот устрашающий текст.
[image: изображение командной строки с ошибкой при установке mod_wsgi]

[image: изображение командной строки с ошибкой при установке mod_wsgi]
Помогите разобраться, что это и как устранить неполадку.

P.S я новичок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Научитесь читать ошибки, он же написал ошибка: требуется Microsoft Visual C++